# HMRC Starter Checklist - Employee Statement

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, employment

I am going on placement next year and I have to fill out the HRMC Starter checklist form. I worked part time (only two shifts) and the pay I received was not taxed. Does that mean I select statement A or B?

A. This is their first job since last 6 April and they have not been receiving taxable Jobseeker's Allowance, Employment and Support Allowance, taxable Incapacity Benefit, state pension or occupational pension.

B. This is now their only job, but since last 6 April they have had another job, or have received taxable jobseeker's allowance, employment and support allowance or taxable incapacity benefit. They do not receive state or occupational pension.

C. They have another job or receive a state or occupational pension

Comment: `part time (only two shifts) and the pay I received was not taxed` Did you have a NI number when you did this job ? Was your pay reported to HMRC ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two shifts you worked were done since the beginning of April then you need to select B. You wouldn't have paid tax on that previous job if it would have fallen within your tax free allowance, however the income is still classed as taxable income and would be added to all other income for the tax year to work out your total tax liability (which is still likely to be 0, but needs to be declared regardless).